# PHP session permission problem

Tags: php, session, permissions

I'm trying to initialize a session but i get this error:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/tmp/sess_7af3ee9ec1350680bedcf63833d160bd, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)

The session.path is set to /tmp with 777 perms.

I try to edit the session.path to "0;777;/tmp" but the session files are created with the wrong permissions(only write).

I'm using PHP 5.2 on apache2 and ubuntu 9.10.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please verify that the permissions of /tmp really are xx777

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$s = stat('/tmp');
printf('%o', $s[2]);
file_put_contents('/tmp/phptest1234.txt', 'test');
unlink('/tmp/phptest1234.txt');
```

edit: next try, [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask)

```
<?php
echo ' php-umask: ', sprintf('%o', umask()), "\n";
echo ' exec-umask: ', exec('umask'), "\n";
```

Comment: Your script returns 44777.
The session files are written in /tmp but with wrong permissions: php create session files with 100366 permissions. I can write but not read.

Comment: It returns:
php-umask: 22 exec-umask: 0022

Comment: That's odd. If you create a file in /tmp on the shell like e.g. `ls -la > /tmp/mytestfile.deleteAtAnyTime` does it also have the mode set to 100366?

Comment: No, the permissions are correctly 644 only session files are created with wrong perms. Maybe there is a bug like this:
http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31323

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you do not have permissions to write to the `tmp` directory, you need to give it permissions to save a file.

Comment: +1: Reminds me of last week when a machine I ran across that someone else set up had /tmp as 0770 instead of 1777 or 1666.  Come to think of it, that was a Ubuntu Server too.

Comment: It looks like he's already stated that /tmp's perms are set to 777.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, as well.  There was a line in /etc/sysconfig/httpd that was setting the umask improperly, so I commented it out:

```
#umask 644
```

All is well now.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the problem, there was a third party library that sets wrong umask to 777, by deleting it the problem was solved. Thanks for answers.