# If I change my PHP session.save_path to anything but /tmp, I get very strange errors

Tags: session-variables, session-cookies, php

I'm not getting any error messages at all (even with error reporting E_ALL turned on) but it creates some very strange behavior with my sessions. I changed the session.save_path to /tmp2 rather than /tmp and I can see the session data being created in that folder when I look using SFTP, but on my web pages it's as if the session variable doesn't exist. Or that it does, but it doesn't match up somehow.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you set the save path on all pages that wish to read sessions? You should do that on every page requiring sessions and follow it by session_start();

PHP has a large number of options set in the php.ini file. These settings are used by default on all pages. If you wish to change this configuration you must either edit the ini, causing a global change to the php settings, or ensure that you make the changes on all pages that require a configuration change.

Assuming that you have set this all up correctly and the session is attempting to initialise, then you might have read access permission problems. Have a look at the read/write permissions on your /tmp directory and ensure your new directory is configured the same way.

See:

[PHP session permission problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058994/php-session-permission-problem)

Comment: Shouldn't it be enough to set the save path in php.ini?

Comment: It sounds like you have it configured correctly. If the session doesn't appear to exist you might not have initialised the session. session_start(); should be at the start of the page if it isn't already.

Comment: thanks for the tips, but everything seems to be set up correctly. I ran into the permissions problem early on, so I already fixed that part.

Comment: What's your setup? Make sure verbose warnings are turned on and post the errors you are receiving. Echo session_save_path() to see what the config is.