# This page isn't working ERROR 500 Savsoft

Tags: https

I uploaded files from SavsoftQuiz_v5.0 to my web server and configured all the necessary files step by step. Tried running the site on the web and it keeps producing an error:
HTTP ERROR 500 - This Page isn't working.

The error logs generated this file

> ERROR - 2020-04-21 22:45:31 --> Severity: error --> Exception:
>   Session: Configured save path '/var/lib/php/session' is not a
>   directory, doesn't exist or cannot be created.
>   /var/www/vhosts/africansurveyors.co.zw/httpdocs/Eduline/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php
>   138

HOW DO I FIX THE PROBLEM?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP session permission problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058994/php-session-permission-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shan is correct, you need to configure your php session to allow write access or to point to a folder you control that actually exists.

Reading a similar usage from https://codeclimate.com/github/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php/source [Line112]
 it looks like you can set "session.save_path" value from php.ini. Set this to something you control, maybe it supports relative paths, go find out!

You may find you have other folders incorrectly set or defaults assigned, like your temp folder. Don't be afraid to get familiar with php.ini if you plan to stick with php things, but backup before you make changes!